# Extract information from functions that returns nested structures with DefineDLLFunction

Tags: .netlink

**Where can I find examples devoted to extracting information from functions that returns nested structures with [`DefineDLLFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/NETLink/ref/DefineDLLFunction.html) in *Mathematica*?**

The only example I found and understood, was given by Todd G[ayley in “calling a dll-function that returns a structure  ”](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2010/Mar/msg00655.html), but this concern a function with only one structure.

**How to pass a nested structure in `DefineDLLFunction` and how to extract the information concerning the nested records from it?**